# How to get the Win32_battery class information of the battery connected to computer through RS 232 Interface?

Tags: c#, c++

I need to get the battery information (Win32_battery class) (using WMI) of the battery connected to the PC through RS 232 Interface(C#.NET app). Can any one help me to get this information?

Comment: -1 This is a pretty obscure question and as such it needs a lot more detail if it is to be answerable.

Answer (score 1):

A battery connected trough the RS232?
Are you sure?
Can you elaborate a bit more?
BTW, you surely have a specification sheet of your connected device.
You must find the schema of the commands and associated data responses that the device ca send to the interface and try to convert that data into a Win32_Battery instance.
If you don't have specs, find the supplier of the device and ask for techincal manuals and sheets.

Comment: Sorry, Now only i am getting, i need to write the my own WMI Provider(Win32_Rajesh class) to communicate with the Managed(Battery Connected to it) COmponent . When the WQL Comes for Win32_Rajesh class, i need to get the info from battery and communicate that class as WQL Response.. I need to write in C#.

Comment: it all depends on the information that the particular device can sen(is specifically programmed to send) on the RS232 interface.

Comment: I hope so. But can any one tell me how long it would take to write a WMI Provider in C#?